# sbt says "not a valid command" but plugin enabled

Tags: sbt

I have a plugin called sonar, which is developed and published as an AutoPlugin:

```
object Sonar extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    lazy val sonar = taskKey[Unit]("sonar")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  lazy val sonarTask = Def.task {

      <snip task code here which runs sonarqube scanner>

  }

}
```

We then have a project which uses that plugin, with `plugins.sbt` that looks like this:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Nexus Snapshot repo" at "url here"
)

credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")

addSbtPlugin("packagename" % "sonar" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

And build.sbt like this:

```
name := "hashing-library"

organization := "org name here"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
autoScalaLibrary := false
crossPaths := false


resolvers += "Nexus Release repo" at "https://nexusurl/content/repositories/releases/"

resolvers += "nexus Snapshot repo" at "https://nexusurl/content/repositories/snapshots/"

credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")

// Publishing options:
publishMavenStyle := true
publishArtifact in Test := false
pomIncludeRepository := { x => false }

publishTo := {
  val nexus = "nexus url here"
  if (isSnapshot.value)
    Some("sonatype-snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
  else
    Some("sonatype-releases" at nexus + "content/repositories/releases")
}
```

When I try to run sbt plugins, it says the plugin is enabled:

```
<snip output>
packagename.sonar.Sonar: enabled in hashingLibrary
```

So why is it that my plugin is enabled, but I cannot run `sbt sonar`?  When I do, it says:

```
[info] Set current project to hashing-library (in build file:/home/work/hashing-library/)
[error] Not a valid command: sonar
[error] Not a valid project ID: sonar
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: sonar
[error] sonar
[error]
```

(Obviously org names and url's have been removed to protect confidentiality of my client, but hopefully that doesn't impact my question!)

Answer (score 0):

The missing part of your plugin is the connection between the `sonar` task *key* and the `sonarTask` task *implementation*, i.e. you need to say somewhere that the key is set to the value of the implementation. You normally do it by overriding project settings in the plugin:

```
override def projectSettings = Seq(
  sonar := sonarTask.value
)
```